# search movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

it seems to me impossible but just checking if there is a magical solution. Assume I have a container movieClip, inside it lies a lot of children movieclips with different names. I wanted to search the children mcs by name using a search criteria whether a regular expression or just a begin-with, end-with + a string. Of course I know that I can loop over the children mcs and filter the ones whose names match my search criteria. But I`m not looking for this approach as it is resource consuming. Also I mustn't return an array of matched mcs, if it can return just the first match is enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep all of the children inside of the container sorted, the search will be a lot faster. You can make your own intelligent Add method which will keep some binary tree of all the names and insert the items into the correct place. (Or you can even add each item and also add a separate instance of its name to a sorted list of names which you add/remove whenever an item is added/removed.)